# Image Upload Ember JS and Sails JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, sails.js

I'm trying to upload an image from the frontend "Ember JS" to "Sails JS",

I've created an API called "upload" and used "skipper" with "gridfs" to upload the image in my Mongo database.

I'm also using "kitematic" virtual server the weird is my code works until it reaches to the

```
req.file('file').upload({
  adapter : require('skipper-gridfs'),
  uri : 'mongodb://192.168.99.100:32769/admin/upload'
})
```

for some reason I get

```
Sending 500 ('server error') response:
{ err : 'connection to [192.168.99:27017] timed out' }
```

I'm using 'ember-file-upload' in Ember, and here is my frontend

template.hbs

```
  {{#file-upload name="file"
            accept="image/*"
            multiple=true
            onfileadd=(action "uploadImage")}}
     <a id="upload-image" tabindex=0>Add an Image.</a>
  {{/file-upload}}
```

controller.js

```
 uploadImage(file) {
  console.log(file);
  file.upload('http://localhost:1338/uploads/file').then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.get('model.files').pushObject({ path : response.body.message });
  })
}
```

Now Sails js upload controller

```
module.exports = { 
    file : function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        req.file('file').upload({
        adapter : require('skipper-gridfs'),
        uri : 'mongodb://192.168.99.100:32769/admin/upload'
        }, function(err, uploadedFiles) {
        if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
        console.log(err);
        return res.json({ message : uploadedFiles[0].fd.split('assets/')[1] })
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, look at the error you get:

```
Sending 500 ('server error') response:
{ err : 'connection to [192.168.99:27017] timed out' }
```

There you have a connection to 192.168.99:27017, which is quite different from what you set:

```
mongodb://192.168.99.100:32769/admin/upload
```

First of all, I think your URI is not right - this /admin/upload does not seem right to me. Try /admin.upload, or omit the whole thing at all, like:

```
mongodb://192.168.99.100:32769
```

Also make sure you can connect to your mongoDB with no username and password.

For reference check this URL: http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html

Comment: sorry for replying late, but that was the true answer, my mistake was that i wrote "admin/upload" the correct syntax was "admin.uploads" as i set pluralize to true, but now i seem to get a new error "MongoError: error processing query: ns=admin.uploads.chunksTree: $and
    files_id $eq ObjectId('5a9ebd442fcb57a306ed1105')
    n $gte 0
Sort: { files_id: 1, n: 1 }
Proj: {}
 No query solutions" any idea about it might help .. Thanks again

Comment: Checkout this link https://github.com/willhuang85/skipper-gridfs/issues/14
Btw, I've never used mongoDB to save files, so can't help further.